# Evitar que uma imagem sobreponha outra no input file

Tags: php

Tenho este código:

```
$img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$diretorio = "imagens/";
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $diretorio.$img);
```

Se eu colocar, por exemplo: bola.png e outro usuário colocar bola.png depois, a imagem dele vai alterar a minha. Eu gostaria de que se já houver esse arquivo na minha pasta imagens e no meu banco de dados, ele apareça como, por exemplo: bola(1).png, depois bola(2).png e assim por diante.

Comment: Acho que você está indo pelo lado mais complicado. Não seria melhor verificar no banco se o nome da imagem existe e cadastrar outro nome?

Comment: Ou pode renomear os arquivos com base em um valor único, tal como `uniqid()`, por exemplo.

Comment: Conforme comentado pelo @AndersonCarlosWoss, melhor é você usar um nome que você controle, e não o usuário que faça o upload. Inclusive, se aproveitar o 'name' original vai ter outros problemas com caracteres especiais.

Comment: seria melhor fazer algo do tipo colocar o timestamp atual junto com o nome do arquivo, que sempre será diferente.

Comment: @Luizinho ou simplesmente adicione um prefixo, tipo um timestamp, como por exemplo 20171218105930_ (ano/mês/dia/hora/min/segundo)

Comment: Dvd o problema é que imagina depois de um tempo em que o site crescer e houver milhões de imagens. O usuário vai ter que ficar tentando adivinhar qual caminho de imagem não existe no banco de dados.

Comment: Anderson, eu pensei em renomear depois como você falou, só que é meio complicado porque eu queria colocar o valor do caminho da imagem no alt da tag img para que pessoas com deficiência visual possam entender do que a imagem se trata.

Comment: Aonde que você salva o diretório?

Comment: _Dvd o problema é que imagina depois de um tempo em que o site crescer e houver milhões de imagens. O usuário vai ter que ficar tentando adivinhar qual caminho de imagem não existe no banco de dados._ Você salva as imagens em diretórios diferentes?

Comment: A ideia do timestamp é boa, não havia pensado nisso, mas não existe a possibilidade de colocar como eu comentei? "bola(1).png", porque eu vejo que quando faço um download ou upload de uma imagem que tem o mesmo nome no meu pc ou no google drive eles automaticamente colocam (1) depois do nome.

Comment: Dvd, não, é em um diretório só: "imagens/".

Comment: Então, como falei no meu primeiro comentário, altere o nome da imagem enviada se já houver uma igual, se é isso que vc quer fazer.

Comment: Luizinho, mas o problema nem é este... o certo é vc tratar o nome do arquivo enviado e não salvar ele com o nome que foi enviado. E se o usuário enviar uma imagem com o nome `sdjhdsjhdsjhjdsjsdhjds dsdshdsghds ghdshdsg.png`? Vai zuar seu site.

Comment: Se o usuário zoar é só punir ou bloquear ele. Quando ele posta alguma coisa, eu sei quem está postando e tem também botão de denuncia que outras pessoas podem usar para denunciar um determinado usuário.  Se alguém agir de maneira inapropriada no stackoverflow, o  pessoal vai punir. A mesma coisa é se alguém quiser zoar o meu site, eu vou punir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta usar **`is_file`** e criar uma **função recursiva** para evitar duplicar

```
function increment_name($path)
{
    //Se o arquivo não existir o nome será aceito
    if (!is_file($path)) {
        return $path;
    }

    //Pega as informações do PATH
    $info = pathinfo($path);

    //Pega o nome sem extensão
    $name = $info['filename'];

    /*
     * Se não houver um formato como "x (1).txt"
     * então inicia do zero para incrementar 1
     */
    $current = 0;


    /*
     * Verifica se já existe algo como "x (1).txt"
     * se existir pega o numero e manda os valores do regex para $out
     */
    if (preg_match('#\((\d+)\)$#', $name, $out)) {
        //Pega o numero que estava entre parenteses
        $current = $out[1];

        //Remove o numero e os parenteses do final
        $name = rtrim(substr($name, 0, -strlen($current)-2));
    }

    //Incrementa um numero
    $name .= ' (' . (++$current) . ')';

    //Checa recursivamente se o NOVO nome já existe ou não
    return increment_name($info['dirname'] . '/' . $name . '.' . $info['extension']);
}

//Usando

$img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$diretorio = "imagens/";
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$new_name = increment_name($diretorio.$img);

move_uploaded_file($tmp, $new_name);
```

---

### Usando uniqid()

Seguindo as sugestões dos comentários, pode usar o `uniqid()` só que tem um problema, ela ***não é 100% garantida*** pois usa o "tempo", então poder contornar o problema você tentar aplicar um `rand()` e também checar se o nome já existe, fazendo uma checagem recursiva

Criei um exemplo:

```
function create_ufilename($name, $path = '.')
{
    //Pega a extensão da imagem original
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    //Gera um nome baseado no tempo
    $id = uniqid(rand(1, 100));

    //Gera o caminho
    $path .= '/' . $id . '.' . $ext;

    //Se existir tentará novamente, caso contrário retornará o novo nome
    return is_file($path) ? create_ufilename($name, $path) : $path;
}

//Usando

$img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$diretorio = "imagens/";
$tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$new_name = increment_name($diretorio.$img);

//Deve passar o nome da imagem e a pasta que deseja salvar, assim:
$salvar = create_ufilename($img, $diretorio);

move_uploaded_file($tmp, $salvar);
```

Comment: a utilização da função [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.tempnam.php) seria mais útil em vez de `uniqid()`?

Comment: @Everson se eu fosse usar isso teria que ficar aplicando chmod pra tudo :/ ... fora que acho que o comportamento em Win e Linux é diferente.

Comment: Entendi, valeu :)

Comment: Opa, consegui aqui. Valeu  ;)